# Running Docker Linux containers on Docker for Windows with volume mounts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a Docker Linux container in a Docker for Windows environment. I'm also using a Dockerfile to docker-compose up for my project.

I'm having trouble getting my volume mounts to mount correctly. Specifically in my [Kitematic](https://kitematic.com/) I can see that the text '\host_mnt' is being added to the beginning of my volume path. So my volume path looks like '\host_mntC:\Users\blah\blah\blah'. The path is correct except that there is the '\host_mnt' being added to the beginning.

My suspicion is that I have to somehow have my volume mount path put in incorrectly in my Dockerfile. I've tried using relative path, using absolute path and using both expanded notation for volumes and the one line way of writing volumes.

Answer (score 5):

Since I am using Docker for Windows, on the Docker icon if you right click and choose Settings, then Shared Drives, you want to make sure that the drive you are using is shared. But also there is an example of how you'd do a bind mount right beneath there.

In the terminal you can run the example:

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data
```

That 'c:/Users:/data' is the way of writing path files for bind mounts in Docker for Windows (as of version 17.12.0-ce-win47).

That same way of writing paths is how you'd write it in the docker-compose.yaml file. If you open up Kitematic the volume still shows up with '/host_mnt' text, but that is OK and it's supposed to.

Comment: In the current version of Docker for Windows, 18.06.0-ce-win70 (19075), I don't see any *"Shared Drives"* option. This is on Windows 10.

Comment: I'm on the previous version to Docker for Windows, also on Windows 10. I'm not able to update right now. But the place to look probably has not changed in one version update. The Shared Drives is the second menu item on the left part of the screen. There's an image at this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/

Comment: Docker for Windows has two modes: Windows Containers Mode, and Linux Containers Mode, which can be switched by right-clicking on the whale icon. "Shared Drives" is only available in Linux Containers Mode. I imagine that in Windows Containers mode it is unnecessary.

Comment: As far as I know Windows Containers Mode is still the uncommon one. Most containers are still built using Linux Containers. So even if you are using a Windows operating system you'd still probably be using Linux Containers Mode as most images are built for creating Linux containers.

Answer (score 0):

If your on computer not available a user password, create an a administrator password. Then, you does on the Docker select shared driver. And write administrator password.

Answer (score 0):

try reset docker to factory defaults. in docker->settings->Reset.

see this https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5563