# not valid windows path when mounting network share in docker for windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-volume

using hyper-v and activated access to mount share in Docker Desktop as here:

[image]

I'm trying to mount Z: into a volume to no avail. Same message always: "not valid windows path"

Tried so far:

```
docker run -it -v Z:\:/mnt alpine
docker run -it -v z:\:/mnt alpine
docker run -it -v Z\:/mnt alpine
docker run -it -v z\:/mnt alpine
docker run -it -v Z/:/mnt alpine
docker run -it -v z\:/mnt alpine
```

[update (using suggested paths)]

```
docker run -it --rm -v Z:/:/mnt alpine
WatsonBucketsNamParamName☺☺♥♥☺☺☺☺☺☺▲System.Collections.IDictionary►System.Excepti☻♠☻↑System.ArgumentException♠♥.La ruta de acceso no tiene un formato válido.

NewNormalizePath
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.IO.Path
System.String NewNormalizePath(System.String, Int32, Boolean)W�♠mscorlib.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

any help would be great!

Comment: This works on my Docker for Windows using: `docker run -it -v Z:/:/mnt alpine`

Comment: Not working. Not a valid windows path.

Answer (score 2):

The following path worked locally for mounting a drive to alpine:

```
docker run -it -v Z:/:/mnt alpine
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48693462/4676641) mentions that you should specify paths in Docker for Windows with `/` instead. I cannot find any documentation on how to provide filepaths on Windows but also found [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/170) Docker forum post mentioning the same thing about replacing `\` with `/`.

Comment: Sorry @Forge. There are other suggestions to use double forward slashes. This must be for the older version of Docker/HyperV which I do not have. `-v //z/:/mnt` or `-v z:/:/mnt`